# Hyperledger Sawtooth cannot start devmode consensus engine

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to start up a Hyperledger Sawtooth network on Ubuntu 16.04. I am following the instructions of https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/ubuntu.html.

Starting up the validation service works fine, but starting the devmode consensus engine does not work. The following happened:

```
mdi@boromir:~$ sudo -u sawtooth devmode-engine-rust -vv --connect tcp://localhost:5050
ERROR | devmode_engine_rust: | ReceiveError: TimeoutError
DEBUG | sawtooth_sdk::messag | Disconnected outbound channel
DEBUG | sawtooth_sdk::messag | Exited stream
DEBUG | zmq:547              | socket dropped
DEBUG | zmq:547              | socket dropped
DEBUG | zmq:454              | context dropped
mdi@boromir:~$
```

The validation service was running, as follows:

```
mdi@boromir:~$ sudo -u sawtooth sawtooth-validator -vv
[sudo] password for mdi: 
[2019-03-07 16:40:15.601 WARNING  (unknown file)] [src/pylogger.rs: 40] Started logger at level DEBUG
[2019-03-07 16:40:15.919 DEBUG    ffi] loading library libsawtooth_validator.so
[2019-03-07 16:40:15.926 DEBUG    ffi] loading library libsawtooth_validator.so
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.299 INFO     path] Skipping path loading from non-existent config file: /etc/sawtooth/path.toml
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.299 INFO     validator] Skipping validator config loading from non-existent config file: /etc/sawtooth/validator.toml
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.300 INFO     keys] Loading signing key: /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.306 INFO     cli] sawtooth-validator (Hyperledger Sawtooth) version 1.1.4
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.307 INFO     cli] config [path]: config_dir = "/etc/sawtooth"; config [path]: key_dir = "/etc/sawtooth/keys"; config [path]: data_dir = "/var/lib/sawtooth"; config [path]: log_dir = "/var/log/sawtooth"; config [path]: policy_dir = "/etc/sawtooth/policy"
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.307 WARNING  cli] Network key pair is not configured, Network communications between validators will not be authenticated or encrypted.
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.333 DEBUG    state_verifier] verifying state in /var/lib/sawtooth/merkle-00.lmdb
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.337 DEBUG    state_verifier] block store file is /var/lib/sawtooth/block-00.lmdb
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.338 INFO     state_verifier] Skipping state verification: chain head's state root is present
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.339 INFO     cli] Starting validator with serial scheduler
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.339 DEBUG    core] global state database file is /var/lib/sawtooth/merkle-00.lmdb
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.340 DEBUG    core] txn receipt store file is /var/lib/sawtooth/txn_receipts-00.lmdb
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.341 DEBUG    core] block store file is /var/lib/sawtooth/block-00.lmdb
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.342 DEBUG    threadpool] Creating thread pool executor Component
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.343 DEBUG    threadpool] Creating thread pool executor Network
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.343 DEBUG    threadpool] Creating thread pool executor Client
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.343 DEBUG    threadpool] Creating thread pool executor Signature
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.345 DEBUG    threadpool] Creating thread pool executor FutureCallback
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.346 DEBUG    threadpool] Creating thread pool executor FutureCallback
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.352 DEBUG    threadpool] Creating thread pool executor Executing
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.353 DEBUG    threadpool] Creating thread pool executor Consensus
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.353 DEBUG    threadpool] Creating thread pool executor FutureCallback
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.358 DEBUG    threadpool] Creating thread pool executor Instrumented
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.368 DEBUG    selector_events] Using selector: ZMQSelector
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.376 INFO     interconnect] Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:4004
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.377 DEBUG    dispatch] Added send_message function for connection ServerThread
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.377 DEBUG    dispatch] Added send_last_message function for connection ServerThread
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.382 DEBUG    genesis] genesis_batch_file: /var/lib/sawtooth/genesis.batch
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.384 DEBUG    genesis] block_chain_id: not yet specified
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.384 INFO     genesis] Producing genesis block from /var/lib/sawtooth/genesis.batch
[2019-03-07 16:40:16.385 DEBUG    genesis] Adding 1 batches
```

This output is on time 17:29, so no output has been appended for almost an hour.

I tried to see Sawtooth settings:

```
mdi@boromir:~$ sawtooth settings list
Error: Unable to connect to "http://localhost:8008": make sure URL is correct
mdi@boromir:~$
```

And I checked what processes were listening to what ports:

```
mdi@boromir:~$ netstat -plnt
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4004          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
mdi@boromir:~$
```

Does anybody know whether the validator service initiates connection or the consensus engine? What is wrong with my `sawtooth settings list` command? And does anybody know how to get the consensus engine to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answers myself. I had another machine with a docker installation of Hyperledger Sawtooth. On that server, the validator log had the line:

```
[2019-03-08 14:39:02.478 INFO     interconnect] Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:5050
```

Port 5050 is used for the consensus engine as stated in https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/ubuntu.html. This makes clear that the consensus engine initiates the connection to the validator service.

So why didn't the validator service listen to port 5050 on my Ubuntu machine? Because the settings transaction processor did not ever run on the Ubuntu machine. I started this processor according to the command in the Ubuntu tutorial:

```
sudo -u sawtooth settings-tp -v
```

Then the validator proceeded and started listening to port 5050. As a consequence, the consensus engine could be started.

Comment: Adding a comment here for the benefit of others. Hyperledger Sawtooth version 1.2 onwards validator has a design such that a consensus engine is registered with it and there wouldn't be any Timeout error as seen in this question. Depending on the settings `sawtooth.consensus.engine.name` and `sawtooth.consensus.engine.version` the appropriate engine will be activated. In either case settings TP plays a role and thus should be always registered.